# How to add Quartz listener in Grails when using the plugin

Tags: grails, listener, quartz-scheduler

I use this plugin: https://grails.org/plugin/quartz. Is there any function to add job listener to Jobs?

Comment: Global listeners, or job specific?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore i have a same issue. can u update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can look at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/blob/master/src/main/groovy/quartz/QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy#L256-L269

```
ListenerManager listenerManager = scheduler.getListenerManager()
KeyMatcher<JobKey> matcher = KeyMatcher.keyEquals(jobDetail.key)
if (listenerManager.getJobListener(listener.getName()) == null) {
    listenerManager.addJobListener(listener, matcher)
} else {
    listenerManager.addJobListenerMatcher(listener.getName(), matcher)
}
```